# Find the pdf of a new random variable that is a power of a uniform distribution

Tags: probability

I'm not sure how to find the pdf for this example

The random variable $U$ follows the distribution $U(0, 1)$ find the pdf of a new random variable $X = U^\alpha$ for $\alpha > 0$.

Comment: One way is to find the CDF and differentiate.

Answer (score 4):

Using the cumulative distribution function (cdf) of $V \stackrel{\rm def}{=}U^\alpha$, denoted $F_V$: for every $t\geq 0$, 
$$
F_V(t) = \mathbb{P}\{ V \leq t \} 
= \mathbb{P}\{ V^{1/\alpha} \leq t^{1/\alpha} \} 
= \mathbb{P}\{ U \leq t^{1/\alpha} \} 
= \begin{cases} t^{1/\alpha} &\text{ if } 0\leq t\leq 1\\
1 &\text{ if } t\geq 1\end{cases}
$$
and $F_V(t) = 0$ if $t<0$. Then, the probability density function of $F_V$ is, by differentiation,
$$
f_V(t) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{\alpha}t^{1/\alpha-1} &\text{ if } 0\leq t\leq 1\\
0 &\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}
$$

**Sanity check:** for $\alpha=1$, we get $f_V(t) = \mathbf{1}_{(0,1)}(t)$ ($V=U$ is uniform on $[0,1)$)